# JUnitReport HTML - Unit Test Results Order

Tags: java, html, junit

Does anyone know if it is possible to order the HTML page generated by the junitreport task in ant to order the test results by timestamp rather than alphabetically by Class name.

The report does show the timestamp but I can't find anyway to sort the results by it.  I would like the default to be sorting by timestamp.

Many thanks,
Stef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to your post above I found the solution which involved using a custom stylesheet (a modified version of [the default xsl file](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/tags/ANT_171/src/etc/junit-frames.xsl?view=markup)) as you suggested.

I changed line 656 from:

```
<xsl:sort select="@name"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:sort select="@timestamp"/>
```

and it did exactly what I wanted.

Thanks again for your help.

Cheers,
Stef

Answer (score 3):

JUnitReport uses XSL stylesheets in order to transform the raw XML files into HTML files. You might change the stylesheets in order to generate custom HTML (and thus sort by timestamp). One your stylesheets work, use the styledir attribute (see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html) to tell ant to use your stylesheets rather than the default ones.

Comment: That's helpful, I'll look into that, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also jQuery tablesorter (tablesorter.com) to the resulting html file to get sorting goodness. That's what I just did. Chrome crashes for some reason, but Firefox and Safari seem ok.